# What is the highest supported micro SD capacity for the Nintendo Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

When the PS4 was updated to support an external Hard Drive [Playstation listed](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2017/02/03/ps4-system-software-update-4-50-features-detailed/)

> This is compatible with HDDs up to 8TB in size.

I just got my Nintendo Switch and am looking to buy a Micro SD for it but when i started to think how big it should be i remembered the PS4 and don't want to get a highest capacity Micro SD Card only to find out that it isn't supported/compatible.

So what is the highest supported micro SD capacity for the Nintendo Switch?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to Nintendo's [support page](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22481/p/897) on the topic:

> The following types of microSD cards are supported on Nintendo Switch:
>
> microSD (up to 2 GB) microSDHC (4 GB - 32 GB) microSDXC (64 GB and
> above)
>
> Important: In order to use a microSDXC card on the Nintendo
> Switch console, a system update is required.

Also, they mention speed class:

> Up to speed class 10 for the SD type (minimum guaranteed speed: 10 MB/sec)
> Up to class 1 for the UHS type (minimum guaranteed speed: 10 MB/sec).

Comment: And the highest capacity supported by the microSDXC standard is 2TB, though good luck getting your hands on one of those right now. I can't find the source right now, but I recall a NoA person stating that the Switch would support 2TB microSDXC cards.

Comment: Lol, in the future, when it gets cracked, one could literally install all available games on such a card.

Comment: @TrudleR already looking forward to that moment ;)

Comment: "In order to use a microSDXC card on the Nintendo Switch console, a system update is required." - Is that system update currently available?  If not then the format should be counted as unsupported for now.

Comment: It is. The Switch will detect your card and update automatically @aroth

Comment: @TrudleR, I doubt it. I have a 256 GB SD card in there, and it's already at half capacity with only a dozen or so games (most of which are indies smaller than 1 GB). Doom, Wolfenstein, and L.A. Noire each require more than 1% of that future 2 TB SD card, and there are already many more games over 10 GB. By the time we can buy such a card, it probably won't be able to hold all games anymore.